# правильно ли я отсортировал правую часть и как вызвать эту сортировку?

Tags: c++

```
Процедура слияния упорядоченных частей массива в буфер-промежуточный массив

void merge(int a[], long left, long split, long right) { long pos1=left; 
    long pos2=split+1; 
    
    long pos3=0;    
    int *temp;
    temp = new int[right-left+1];
    while (pos1 <= split && pos2 <= right)
    
    {
    if (a[pos1] < a[pos2]) { temp[pos3] = a[pos1]; pos3++;pos1++;} else {temp[pos3] = a[pos2]; pos3=pos3++;pos2++;}
    
    }
    while (pos1 <= split) 
    
    { temp[pos3] = a[pos1]; pos3++;pos1++;}
    
    while (pos2 <= right) 
    
    { temp[pos3] = a[pos2]; pos3++; pos2++; }
    for (pos3 = 0; pos3 < right-left+1; pos3++) a[left+pos3] = temp[pos3];
    delete [] temp;
    }
```

Процедура непосредственного упорядочение массива

```
void mergeSort(int a[], long left, long right) { long split;    
if (left<right)

{

split = (left + right)/2;
mergeSort(a, left, split); 

mergeSort(a,right,split);????

merge(a,  left, split, right);  
}
}
```

Comment: Если она правильно отсортирована, значит, отсортировали верно. Вызвать функцию можно по ее названию, добавив потом ее аргументы в скобках: `mergeSort(a, left, right)`, где `a, left, right` - ваши конкретные переменные. Но вообще я советую вам перечитать алгоритм сортировки слиянием и переписать ваш код сначала.

Comment: если есть массив то как вызвать с помощью этой функции int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8 };

Comment: Если первый mergeSort вы вызываете от left до split, то очевидно, что второй надо вызывать для интервала от split+1 до right / Ну и на  саму merge посмотрите повнимательней. Реально вы всегда будете сливать вместе **смежные отрезки**. Следовательно, первый можно сразу скопировать в tmp[] и потом сливать tmp[] со вторым отрезком по месту первого. Тогда, если в конце останутся какие-то элементы в tmp[], то их надо просто скопировать, а если там ничего не осталось, то элементы второго отрезка уже на своем месте.

Comment: спасибо, но я ничего не понял

Comment: Смотрите. `split = (left + right)/2;
mergeSort(a, left, split);` это правильно. А вот это `mergeSort(a,right,split);????` неверно, right и split надо поменять местами. Точнее, (глядя на код вашей  merge() можно понять, что right это последний элемент) надо `mergeSort(a,split + 1, right);` / Теперь понятно?

Comment: а как вызвать функцию для сортировки что именно надо прописать?